# How can statistical tests be categorized?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

There are many tests in statistics. I noted that some of them may be grouped together, since they are used for similar purposes. For example

- tests of independence
- tests that compare distributions (Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Shapiro-Wilk, Chi-Square)
- tests that compare location parameters (Student t-test, ANOVA, Kruskal-Wallis, Mann-Whitney)
- tests that compare variances in groups

Are there any other groups of tests with similar use?
Of course, there are also many tests that are too specific and cannot be assigned to any group.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Best" in what sense, exactly? After all, there are infinitely many ways to create categories. What is the purpose of grouping them?

Comment: Title in my question has been edited and there was no "best" word before. But main purpose of grouping is to bring any meaningful system into large number of tests that are used. My idea is described in question body (i.e. categorization based on whole distributions, location parameters, scale parameters and so on) but I do not know if any other categorization is available.

Comment: Could you explain the point of grouping the tests in the first place?

Comment: Original idea was to simplify the problem "how to choose appropriate test" for students of statistics by grouping similar tests together in order to make it more clear that for some hypotheses there may be more than one alternative how to test it.

Comment: Just to validate that - I think Miroslav's idea would have have some value for me.

Comment: That sounds like an answer rather than a question! You are now saying you would like to group tests by their hypotheses.  What, then, is the question?  I'm sure it's not "please list all statistical tests grouped by their hypotheses," because that would be so broad as to be unanswerable.

Comment: I think that most hypotheses in statistics are associated with just one test (if we do not assume resampling techniques). But there are some where many tests have been proposed. So my question is only about those hypotheses, where many approaches how to test them exist.

Comment: Tests or modeling approaches are often categorized by the nature of their dependent variable.  That is, is the measured variable a count, a continuous measured variable, an ordinal variable, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of material available online regarding this. The one I found most useful is by University of Minnesota (link attached below). Most of these resources categorize statistics tests based on what is being evaluated. Below are the main categories that I found:

1. Test for correlation
2. Comparison of means (t-test, ANOVA)
3. Regression Test to predict if change in one variable will change another variable

Look at [this](https://cyfar.org/types-statistical-tests) and [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat500/node/67) links to get some more details.